# whats a good way to optimize a table? SQL server 2k8

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing

Consider a table 'Orders' with 4 columns

OrderNumber : DealerNumber : Code : Time

There's a non clustered index on OrderNumber, DealerNumber and Code. Time does not have on

So

```
select * from Orders where OrderNumber = 10 and DealerNumber = 20
```

is pretty fast.
But the bigger the table gets the more duplicates are retrieved. An order from 2010 can be found and one from 2014.
So I changed the query into

```
select *
from Orders
where OrderNumber = 10 and DealerNumber = 20 and [Time] > getdate() - 180
```

But this will change the execution time of the query from < 1 second to >30 minutes so thats not an option.

I heard something about filtered indexes. Would it be wise to put a filtered index on [Time] column? If so will generating the index take a long time?

Or are there better options to let the second query run very fast?

Comment: Why don't just include `Time` into your existed index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index that you should be thinking about for this query is `Orders(OrderNumber, DealerNumber, [Time])`.

However, I am not sure why the first version would be so fast and the second so slow.  Here are three possibilities:

- You are measuring the performance by the time to the first record being returned, and the first query really does take a long time.
- There is an index on `time` and the optimizer is getting confused because and using that index instead.
- Some other process has locked the table.

I don't think a filtered index would be particularly helpful for this query.

By the way, `getdate()` has a time component on the date.  So you might want:  `[Time] > cast(getdate() - 180 as date).

Comment: you were right, it had nothing to do with the [Time] columns, when I tested it a while ago it was something else that accidently caused the slowness and I assumed it was this. Doesn't matter that the question is void, learned a few SQL things anyway